# how to go back to the previous directory just by double clicking on ubuntu

Tags: doubleclick

i'm new in linux, when I used to have windows 10, I had an app named Clover which I could go to the previous directory just by double clicking in an empty space. I wander is there any way to do that in ubuntu too? if yes, I will appreciate if you tell how to do that.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find my answer.

Nemo File manager is the solution.

```
sudo apt install nemo
nemo
```

To enable going to the parent folder by double clicking,
Open File > Preferences > Behavior
Then check the box for "Double click on a blank area to go to the parent folder".

[image: screen shot]